# Prebuild and ready ISO openstack all-in-one node

Tags: virtual-machine, openstack, openshift-origin

I want to run Openshift origin over Openstack. My current problem is that i can't run openstack on a fedora 20 virtual machine. I've searched many online tutorials and followed the instructions. even quickstarts cause me exceptions. So do not link me to any of them. My question is that is there any Ready Openstack VM or ISO? I mean something that I load into VMWare and by default has a all in one openstack over an linux-based OS like fedora. Can anyone give me direct link to that ISO o vdmk file?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried packstack to install openstack on your fedora machine?
It's pretty easy to install openstack using the packstack utility. It uses the puppet scripts to do the installation of all components. You just need to generate an answer file and modify it according to your need and the use it.

Documentation can be found here  https://openstack.redhat.com/Quickstart .